# Chromium WebView instead of Native WebView

Tags: macos, cocoa, webkit, chromium, chromium-embedded

Is it possible to use a Chromium webview instead of the native webview on OSX? 
I am guess it is a products like Sencha Desktop Packager exist.

*As far as I can tell there drop no convenient libraries/wrappers, but most searches for OSX dev return results for a certain handheld device.*

**Note**
So far I have found CEF and CEFSimpleSample

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use a Chromium webview instead of a native webview. But the documentation to code such a thing is very rare and poor.
The Chromium Embedded Framework Forum is a good place to ask questions.

I would highly recommend you to alter the CEFSimpleSample because there is a "Chromium Webview" included which works.